# Hiding some GET parameters from URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect, friendly-url

I am redirecting page using PHP header location:

Current URL in browser

```
 https://mywebsite/open/firstpage/php/start.php?&cnt=us&language=en&url=http://secureURL.com
```

but want to show

```
https://mywebsite/open/firstpage/php/start.php?&cnt=us&language=en
```

I am using GET method on the other side to collect all variables. I have to hide `&url` in querystring but want to receive it on other side `$_GET['url']`

How can I share my `&url` without showing in URL querystring? HOw can I write htaccess?

Comment: If `&url=...` is removed from original string then it won't be available as `$_GET['url']`

Comment: @anubhava I have keep `&url=` in URL, but dont want to show in broesers URL

Comment: What does that mean? If browsers doesn't see some part of URL that means they will not send that to your web server as well.

Answer (score 2):

Redirect for all URLs

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1?%{QUERY_STRING}&url=http://secureURL.com [L]
```

Redirect for only `/open/firstpage/php/start.php`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/open/firstpage/php/start.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1?%{QUERY_STRING}&url=http://secureURL.com [L]
```

I think this is what you want.

Comment: Yes,but still I am not sure if all urls needed to be redirected or just the one mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. If a parameter is not present in the query string, it won't be available anywhere, it's just not there. There's no such thing as "hiding" the query string.

You could, however, use some form of session mechanism to pass a piece of data from one page to another. You could put it in the $_SESSION, or use cookies. There *may* also be a way to achieve this through really arcane mod_rewrite magic, but you shouldn't go down that route. Really.

More importantly: what are you trying to achieve? Why are you trying to do this?

Aesthetic reasons? Then be aware that modern browsers tend to hide the query string part of the URI from the user.

Security reasons? Then you're doing it horribly wrong, you shouldn't use something so easily manipulated by the client.

User tracking? There are established solutions out there for that (say, Google Analytics).

Comment: I am now applying Security salt, I will share it with thirdt paarty they will check RSA on it. Finally both hash values should be same